# array.shift() not working in an axios response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that i set like so:

```
let application = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(Applications.Offline) || '[]');
```

I then grab the first object in the array:

```
let app = application[0];
```

After this, I run an axios call:

```
Axios.post('API here')
  .then(response => {
    if(response.data.ErrorMessage === 'OK'){
        application.shift();
    }
  })
```

Now, this all sits inside a function, that gets run with setInterval every 5 minutes.

The first time it runs, it works fine. I have console.logged application and it decreased from 7 objects to 6. But every other time after that, it just stays at 6.

If `.shift()` is working, shouldn't it cycle down to 0 objects in the array? That's what I want it to do anyway.

Comment: Did you verify first that `application.shift()` is even executed? It might not be. The promise could be rejected or the condition could be false.

Comment: Are you putting `application` back in local storage after shifting? Because otherwise you're always shifting from a replenished array

Comment: It's really hard to say without knowing the scope of the variables and how they are called. Please provide a [mre], or at least enough code that one can step through the code mentally and get an idea of how it's being run.

Comment: `|| '[]';` should be in the `JSON.parse` otherwise you have an array or a default value of a string

Comment: @apokryfos or just remove the quotes around the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only shifting the `application` array which is a completely separate variable from what you have in your local storage. `JSON.parse` creates a new reference when executed. To solve this, you'll need to set the shifted variable back to the local storage after processing the object.

```
if (response.data.ErrorMessage === 'OK') {
    application.shift();
    localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(Applications.Offline, application));
}
```

Comment: As per my comment, that's what I thought as well, but we can't be sure since OP didn't post enough code to tell for certain.

Comment: yes this works thank you. I had actually done this before i cam here, but this is the correct answer..